# Partition the set of naturals from $1$ to $16$ into two subsets satisfying certain conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I want to partition the set $S=(1,2,3,...,16)$ into two subsets $A=(a_1,a_2,...,a_8) $ and $B=(b_1,b_2,...,b_8)$ such that:$$[1]\;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^{8}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{8}b_i$$
And:$$[2]\;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^{8}a_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^{8}b_i^2$$
And:$$[3]\;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^{8}a_i^3=\sum_{i=1}^{8}b_i^3$$
I tried some configurations, I found that $A=(1,4,6,7,9,12,14,15)$ and $B=(2,3,5,8,10,11,13,16)$ satisfy $[1]$ and $[2]$ but not $[3]$, I figured out that the sum in $[3]$ should be $9248$ but I'm kinda stuck, I don't know what else I could do other than painstakingly compute other configurations...

Comment: There are constraints on the solutions to 1 and 2 ,maybe calculate those if you know modular arithmetic

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What bothers me is that the process is generalizable, i.e. one can partition any set from $1$ to $2^{m+1}$ where $m$ is a positive integer into two sets such that all the sums of the elements raised to a power not exceding m are equal, not only that, if $d$,$m$ are positive integers the set of numbers from $1$ to $d^{m+1}$ can be subdivided into $d$ disjoint subsets such that for any polynomial of degree not exceeding $m$, the sum of it's values over any of the subsets is the same. So there must be a more efficient way other than using modular arithmetic

Comment: sure, but parity alone knocks out nearly 999 of every 1000 just from equation 1.

Comment: okay not quite, but the number of ways to select 4 odd out of 8 odd, is 70, ( There needs to be an even number of them in at least 1 set or an odd number in both so parity matches.) which is less than 255 to select any subset of 8. and technically if it were any random size subset of 16 integers there would be 65535 non-empty selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $A=\{1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16\}$?

Comment: Now it's fine! How did you find this configuration in particular? my textbook states that for any set from $1$ to $2^{m+1}$ where $m$ is a positive integer one can partition it into two sets such that all the sums of the elements raised to a power not exceding m are equal

Comment: @LordShark I got this too with a computer search (Python).  Was that your method...or did you do something more theoretical?

Comment: I know the trick. For $n=32$, up to fourth powers, try $A=\{1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16,18,19,21,24,25,28,30,31\}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Hum, I see that "to go from one set to the next one" (say from m=3 to m=4) you keep the old set and add the new elements in some way, you follow some kind of algorithm?

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic: the algorithm is simple: $A_{2n}=A_n\cup (B_n+n)$.